# Select all .even elements if more than 1 children

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a list of `.field-item`. They are all `.even` or `.odd`. (They start with `.even`, which is not the CSS way, but it's not up to me.)

I want every `.even` (first child is `.even`) to have a background color IF there are more than 1 children in the list.

These won't work:

- `.even`, because it includes the 1st item if there's only 1
- `.even:not(:last-child)`, because it excludes the 3rd item if there are 3
- `.field-item + .field-item.even`, because it doesn't include the 1st item, ever

This one does work, but it's a double and that's always a shame:

```
.field-item.even:not(:last-child),   /* includes first, not last */
.field-item + .field-item.even       /* includes last, not first */
```

I'm sure this is possible with a single selector, but I can't figure it out. Maybe something with `:nth-last-child()` or something...? All is fair.

PS. Using `:nth-child(odd)` is fine too. Giving all items a color and undoing half is NOT fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could combine [`:not()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not)/[`:only-child`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-child) to achieve this.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/7ne4m5tv/)

```
.field-item.even:not(:only-child)
```

```css
.field-item.even:not(:only-child) {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="field-item even">even</div>
    <div class="field-item odd">even</div>
    <div class="field-item even">even</div>
</div>

<hr> 
    
<div class="parent">
    <div class="field-item even">even (only child)</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect. I didn't know that one. It's not even new... Thanks!